# Ruby scan anonymous function explanation

Tags: ruby, syntax, anonymous-function

I new to Ruby and struggling to understand what is going on in this bit of code I wrote.  Why do I have to declare two variables `|x,y|` to get the output I am expecting?  I am only using `x` and `y` always appears to be `nil`.  But when I change to `|x|`, my word count is always `0` (see code and output below).  Thanks for any insight you may be able to provide.

```
def count_words(string)
  string.downcase!

  wordhash = Hash.new

  # what is going on here?  
  # Why do I have to have two 
  # variables in the scan block?
  string.scan(/(\b\w+\b)/){|x,y|
    wordhash.store(x,string.scan(/\b#{x}\b/).length)}

  return wordhash
end

puts count_words("Hello there.  This is bob bob bob")

# Correct Output with |x,y|:
# {"hello"=>1, "there"=>1, "this"=>1, "is"=>1, "bob"=>3}

# Incorrect Output with |x|:
# {["hello"]=>0, ["there"]=>0, ["this"]=>0, ["is"]=>0, ["bob"]=>0}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan)?

Comment: @NiklasB, Yes.  But my mistake is not completely obvious to me yet.  Just by looking at the output, x appears to be a string in one case but an array in the other.  But I do not understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: Try the following: `proc { |x,y| p x, y }.call([1,2])`. See how the array is destructured into `x` and `y` automatically? In your case it's more like `proc { |x,y| p x, y }.call([1])`, `y` will just be `nil`, because the given array is not long enough.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that :) Fair enough, removed my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer correctly explains why this doesn't work as expected. Let me try to point out some more problems with your code:

- `string.downcase!` modifies the argument given to the function, which is extremely bad style
- `/(\b\w+\b)/` you don't need an additional match group here, simply use `/\b\w+\b/`. This will allow you to just use `scan(...) do |x|`, where `x` will be the matched word
- `wordhash.store(x,y)` can simply be written as `wordhash[x] = y`
- `string.scan(/\b#{x}\b/).length` you scan the string a second time, although that is not necessary. Instead, you can just increment a counter for every match of a given word.

Example:

```
def count_words(string)
  # set up a hash that accumulates the number of occurrences per word
  wordcount = Hash.new(0)
  string.downcase.scan(/\b\w+\b/) { |word| wordcount[word] += 1 }
  # no need to use return here, the function already evaluates to the last
  # value
  wordcount
end

p count_words("Hello there.  This is bob bob bob")
# => {"hello"=>1, "there"=>1, "this"=>1, "is"=>1, "bob"=>3}
```

This is just to demonstrate how your approach could be made working, in Ruby you'd probably solve this in a more functional way, preferrably using [`group_by`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by), as Michael already demonstrated or using [`inject`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject):

```
string.downcase.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,word| h[word] += 1; h }
```

Comment: +1  Thank you!  This makes sense to me now.  I should have also mentioned that I am rather new to RegEx too.

Comment: +1. BTW: since `Fixnum`s are immutable, the simpler `Hash.new(0)` also works.

Comment: @Michael: Very nice to now! I'll add a simple one-liner featuring this.

Comment: Here's one possible one-liner: `s.downcase.scan(/\b\w+\b/).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, word| h[word] += 1; h }`

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, that's about what I already added to the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the `String#scan` documentation:

> If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an
>   array containing one entry per group.

Since your pattern contains a group, the first block argument is an array. If you use `|x, y|` you destructure the array and assign its first element to `x`.

By the way, for getting a hash of word counts, you can just do this:

```
s = "this is a test string it is"
Hash[s.split.group_by{ |e| e }.map { |k,v| [k, v.size] }] 
#=> {"this"=>1, "is"=>2, "a"=>1, "test"=>1, "string"=>1, "it"=>1}
```

Comment: +1, but I think you might need to add a `.downcase` call somewhere to make sure that different capitalizations are flattened into one group.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Yes, downcase probably makes sense. As my code was only meant as an example, details are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @J.Hendrix: Is there anything I should add to the answer for you to accept it? Any more questions? :-)

Comment: +1,nice solution. And congrats for getting gold ruby badge today :)

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau No gold Ruby badge yet. But #10 in the all time Ruby answerers. It's just hard to fight of Marc-Andre ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKohl - you will get it today at night :) You have 999 in ruby tag and I made +1 ;)